# How to enable/disable DNS lookups in Weblogic 10.3?

Tags: dns, weblogic

In Apache-Tomcat I have the **enableLookups** property (i. for [Tomcat 6](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html)) for enabling or disabling the DNS look up. Is there any way of doing the same in Weblogic 10.3?

I have tried with -Dweblogic.system.enableReverseDNSLookups=false but with no luck...

Thanks in advance,

Luis

Comment: That is the correct option for disabling reverse lookups. Why do you think its not working ?

Comment: Hello Kevin, thanks for anwsering! Because when I invoke getRemoteHost() I am getting the hostname instead of the "dotted-string form of the IP address". Probably I am missing something...

Comment: getRemoteHost() is supposed to return the hostname ; if you want the ip address you need to use getRemoteAddr()

Comment: Hello Kevin, thanks again. Yes you are absolutely right, but the thing is that the API says that "If the engine cannot or chooses not to resolve the hostname (to improve performance), this method returns the dotted-string form of the IP address".

Comment: I am slightly confused on your request. Your original query talked about reverse DNS lookup (ip to hostname) and now you are referring to forward DNS lookup (hostname to ip). What exactly are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your answer. I think that I am misunderstanding this two concepts...